# How to init a module by a service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Angular App with main-component AppComponent that uses a module MyMod that needs config information at start.

I also have a service MyServ that provides these information.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  
    MyMod.forRoot ({
         param: "12345"             // the parameter!
            })
  ],
  providers: [MyServ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**myserv.service.ts**

```
@Injectable ()
export class MyServ
{
 
  getParam () : string
  {
    return "12345";
  }
}
```

Is it possible I can use myserv.getParam () in app.modules.ts to init MyMod??

Comment: Does `MyMod` really need this parameter, or does other components/services in the module need the parameter? Is the parameter hardcoded or from an API call or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the method as static, to access directly, please find below a working example!

ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import 'zone.js';
import { SOME_STRING } from './test/test.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(@Inject(SOME_STRING) private someString: string) {
    this.name = someString;
  }
}
```

app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestModule } from './test/test.module';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    TestModule.forRoot({
      param: TestService.getParam(), // the parameter!
    }),
  ],
  providers: [TestService],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor() {}

  static getParam(): string {
    return '12345';
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fdlbau)